# Eclipse PDT debugging requests from node.js server

Tags: node.js, eclipse, xdebug

I need to run xdebug in Eclipse for handling  requests from node.js server app. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug